# A first countable pseudocompact extension space

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a first countable space which is embeded as a subsapce of a first countable pseudocompact extension space $Y=X\cup C$, where C is countable.

> **Question:** If $X$ has countable extent, does $Y$ have countable extent?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumptions on $X$ and $Y$ seem irrelevant: if $Y = X \cup C$, with $C$ countable, and $A \subset Y$ is closed and discrete, and uncountable, then $A \cap X$ must be uncountable and it is still closed and discrete (in $X$). This cannot be, by assumption. So the extent of $Y$ is also countable. The same holds for spread as well.